# Configure nginx for Rails staging and production deployment with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano

How can I modify my `nginx.conf` file to work on deployment with `Capistrano` for both my staging and production environments without having to modify it whenever I deploy to one or the other?

This is my current file:

```
upstream app_server {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.mysite.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mysite.com;

  root /home/deploy/apps/mysite/current/public;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if (-f $request_filename/index.html) {
      rewrite (.*) $1/index.html break;
    }

    if (-f $request_filename.html) {
      rewrite (.*) $1.html break;
    }

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what kind of server you use `unicorn, puma`?

Comment: Using unicorn at the moment

Comment: We've got Nginx working with Passenger - I'll post an answer for you

Comment: @8vius did you end up solving this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I made [capistrano-unicorn-nginx plugin](https://github.com/bruno-/capistrano-unicorn-nginx) in case you don't want to mess with manually editing nginx config files.

Answer (score 1):

And for Unicorn, working config for any environment, just changed domain/root to example.com:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com/current/public;

    location ~* ^/assets/ {
      expires 1y;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
      add_header Last-Modified "";
      add_header ETag "";
      break;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

    # Rails error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
      root /var/www/example.com/current/public;
    }
}

upstream app_server {
   server unix:/tmp/unicorn.example.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

Comment: I currently have a similar configuration. But my issue is actually how can I have one config that works for my staging server and another for my production server and be able to deploy via capistrano without having to modify the files for each instance. I think I should clarify this in my question.

Comment: Well, I usually have similar settings for all environments (not OS, but LEMP software, project folders) and don't need different configs for Unicorn, just set needed environment in /etc/environments, e.g.:

export RAILS_ENV='production'

and Unicorn like any other Ruby-related app knows this setting. As for nginx.conf, it just dont bother about Ruby environments. Sorry if my answer off-topic :)

Comment: Not really it's my bad, but I'm talking specifically about setting the server attribute, it's different for my staging and production environments and whenever I have to deploy to one or the other I have to change it to have it work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I use nginx and passenger, I think it should be similiar.  Here's what I did:

I created an additional nginx configuration file for staging named nginx-staging.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  # server_name www.mydomain.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env staging;
  root /var/www/<app-name>/current/public;

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  # client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Maybe with another app server, you would use "rails_env" instead of "passenger_app_env", I'm not sure.

Then I have a separate task for symlinking the file depending on the environment:

```
namespace :setup do

    ...

    desc "Symlinks config files for Nginx"
    task :symlink_config do
        on roles :app do

            # Here we fetch the rails_env and see if it is staging,
            # if it is, you use that nginx-staging.conf, else you use the standard one for production
            if fetch(:rails_env) == :staging
                execute "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx-staging.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{fetch :application}"
            else
                execute "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{fetch :application}"
            end
        end
    end
end

namespace :deploy do

   ...

    before :deploy, "deploy:check_revision"
    after :deploy, "deploy:restart"
    after :rollback, "deploy:restart"

    # Add this task to run before restarting nginx
    before :restart, "setup:symlink_config"
end
```

I think you can adapt this symlink task to however you setup your server.  You may be using sites-avaliable and have another symlink there to sites-enabled.  So you need to change it according to your specific setup.

Answer (score -1):

Following the tutorial so well laid out at this site: [GoRails VPS Installation](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04), we installed Passenger with Nginx (works really well, too!)

With this, we were able to use the following setup to accept incoming requests to our Rails apps:

```
#etc/nginx/sites-available/your_site
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name yoursite.com;
        root /apps/your_app/public;
        passenger_enabled on;   
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

I can provide more information if you want - this is just what we are using right now

Comment: Similar to what I currently have. I must apologize since my question was vague, I actually need a file that will work for both my environments on deployment through capistrano. Meaning I need a config that can work on ´staging.mysite.com´ and ´mysite.com´ without having to modify for each whenever I deploy.